Credete opportuno creare la tag "mathematics"? / Would it be worth to create a "mathematics" tag?
In questo momento ci sono sul sito parecchie domande che hanno a che vedere con la terminologia nell'ambito della matematica. Secondo me, forse sarebbe una buona idea etichettarle con una tag mathematics (e creare anche il sinonimo matematica). Questo tipo di "tag" esiste anche su altri siti SE dedicati a altre lingue.
Cosa ne pensate?

Penso non sia una cattiva idea (costa qualcosa farlo? perdonate l'ignoranza)

@Easymode44: No, è semplicissimo:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/146950/. Posso farlo io stessa senza problema. Potresti postare quello che hai detto come risposta in modo che gli utenti possano votare positivamente o negativamente la proposta?

Penso sia una buona idea, considerando che la comunità è popolata da utenti che campano di matematica o quasi. Vi sono molti casi di tecnicismi sulla frontiera della disciplina per i quali è difficile trovare traduzioni immediate in italiano. Per quanto vi siano parecchie fonti che fanno da ponte tra l'italiano e l'inglese, ciò non è sempre il caso, come dimostrano domande già poste sul sito.

È passata più di una settimana da quando si è posta la domanda e ha ricevuto soltanto questa risposta con tre voti, cioè, ci sono quattro utenti che sono d'accordo con la proposta. Forse non ce ne sono tanti, ma capisco anche che è arrivata in mal momento. Procedo a creare la "tag" e il sinonimo. Etichetterò le domande pertinenti a poco a poco per non creare un casino nella  "front page".

Adesso siamo in cinque :).

Ho trovato anche questo, ma è veramente molto povero e parecchie delle traduzioni in spagnolo non sono corrette.
